# Using Python's sys.argv to return function results to command line?

Tags: python, linux, arguments, command-line-arguments

I have a file that I've made executable.  It has a function in it that I would like to return its results to the command line but, I keep getting NameError messages.  To break things down, I'm using LinuxMint Lisa and so far I have:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import mechanize
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import sys

def dictionary(word):
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    response = br.open('http://www.dictionary.reference.com')
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.form['q'] = word
    br.submit()
    definition = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read())
    trans = definition.findAll('td',{'class':'td3n2'})
    fin = [i.text for i in trans]
    query = {}
    for i in fin:
        query[fin.index(i)] = i
    return query

print dictionary(sys.argv)
```

Then I chmod from my terminal:

```
sudo chmod +x this_file.py
```

When I call this file from the command-line, I'll enter:

```
./this_file.py 'pass'(or any other string argument)
```

Which will return:

```
TypeError: Must assign a string
```

So I know I'm obviously not using sys.argv correctly but, I have a feeling like I'm mucking something else up when attempting to return this functions results to the command-line.

Comment: in `print dictionary(agrv)` argv is misspelled. Also, use `sys.argv`

Comment: It's better to provide the full trace-back to give the error message some context - esp information about line number where the error occurs.

Comment: Also, you might consider posting a different question instead of "evolving" this one. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I might as well post this as my answer instead of just a comment:

In

```
print dictionary(agrv)
```

`argv` is misspelled.

It should be

```
print dictionary(sys.argv)
```

Also, use `sys.argv`, `argv` by itself won't suffice

Comment: When I use `sys.arvg` I get a syntax error.  So `def dictionary(sys.argv):` is incorrect?

Comment: @tijko `sys.arv` is incorrect, it's `sys.argv` (note the "g"). What you call your parameter your function header (the line with the `def`) is totally up to you though, but in the call you do need the right name.

Comment: Yeah, I need to be much more careful with spelling on here.  What I had in the file was `sys.argv`.

Comment: @tijko I usually would copy-paste code from elsewhere to here, too much risk of typos otherwise :) Did this solve your problem?

Comment: I'm returning a TypeError now.

Comment: @tijko That might be a different problem (and post) perhaps. Does it occur on this line by chance?    `br.form['q'] = argv`

Comment: I've edited my post to what I have(with spelling mistakes corrected).

Answer (score 2):

argv is an attribute of the `sys` module

Use either

`sys.argv`

or do

`from sys import argv`

Comment: I figured that but, for some reason I remember seeing that argv was used by itself?

Comment: if you write `import sys` you'd have to use `sys.argv`, else if wrote `from sys import argv` you'd have to use `argv`. And both would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it have been `print dictionary(sys.argv[1])`. I guess you want to search the commandline argument in the dictionary.com

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the question as currently posted is that sys.argv is a list, not a string, so when you set the form entry 'q' you are setting it to a list of arguments to the program.  You could change the program to pass in the first argument:

```
print dictionary(sys.argv[1])
```

Or call the dictionary functions multiple times:

```
for i in sys.argv[1:]:
    print dictionary(i)
```

Note that we don't want to include the program name itself so omit sys.argv[0].

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I haven't used sys.argv much and it shows.  I thought that **kwargs used lists,tuples, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You don't make it clear what you mean by 'returning' results to the command line. If you just want to print the results, you can do `print`.

But the error message you're getting has nothing to do with that. It's caused by two things: one, you've put `agrv` instead of `argv`. And second, you've imported `sys`, so you need to reference `sys.argv` not just `argv`.

Comment: Your dictionary function can call its argument whatever it likes. But you must *call* it (the last line in your code) with `dictionary(sys.argv)`. This has nothing to do with argv specifically.